# JWS - getting resources in jar and resource management

Tags: java, deployment, resources, embedded-resource, java-web-start

[image: This is what my file structure looks like]

I call my image like this:

```
ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("../res/image1.gif"));
```

When I run this from the command line `java -jar "testWebStartRes.jar"` my image loads.
When I deploy it as a web start application on a GlassFish server image is not found when launching it from the JNLP.

Stack Trace:

```
    Detected from bootclasspath: C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\jre\\lib\\deploy.jar
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at main.Main.setAppIcon(Main.java:42)
    at main.Main.<init>(Main.java:19)
    at main.Main$1.run(Main.java:34)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Null Image
```

**EDIT:** Made question more understandable. Andrew Thompson solved how a web start app should be deployed using a separate jar.

Comment: 1) *"is there a better way that wont require recompiling the jar on changing some data?"*  That statement almost implies that source code needs to be recompiled to generate a new Jar.  It doesn't.  2) I would typically put image (and most other) resources in a separate Jar that is on the run-time class-path of the app. - for a number of reasons. 3) Are you sure the image is in a Jar on the run-time class-path?  JWS apps. can 'phone home' to their own server for loose (unjarred) resources, but whether it makes sense to do that here is not clear.  Is that image an application resource?

Comment: *"my image does not appear to load"*  The stack stack trace should be informative.  Make sure the [console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is open.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is a good point, I see the java tutorials put resources in a separate jar. I will look up the best way to do this.  Yes the images and xml are application resources; I intend to put all my strings in XML for multilingual support and the images will be dynamically displayed within the application depending on the users actions in the GUI.  BTW, Thank you, I love getting the help of genuis professionals.

Comment: *"I love getting the help of genuis professionals."*  So do I!  Can you introduce me to some of them?  ;)

Comment: BTW - I am guessing you've figured some things out since posting the `llegalArgumentException: input == null!`.  Is your question effectively solved, or still in progress?

Comment: I know I am missing something basic but why does `ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("../res/image1.png"))` work in default start configuration and not web start?

Comment: *"work in default start configuration and now web start?"*  Huh?  1) DYM *"and **not** web start?"* 2) By *"default start configuration"* DYM *" jar with default deployment"*?  -- If so to both, the answer probably lies in the fact that the 'current directory' is usually on the class-path of an app.  So the JVM will also look for loose resources within that path.  JWS resources OTOH **have** to be in a Jar on the run-time class-path, in order to be found by `getResource(..)`.

Comment: ah it is a run-time class-path issue.  When the images are in the same package `SRC/main/Main.java` and `SRC/main/image1.gif` i can use `ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("image1.gif"));` to load the image successfully.  So if i want to use a separate package I must tell my IDE to add them to the run-time class-path.  Sorry for the rabbit trail.

Comment: *"images are in the same package"*  I realize you are experimenting to figure out how it works, but in case there is any doubt in your mind, let me emphasize something.  Don't put images and classes in the same directory/package. I recommend all resources should be in a path that is explicitly & only for resources.  If you have multiple signed Jars, with 'same path' in 'different jars' it confuses the JRE, which will issue an obscurely worded warning before considering the entire app. compromised (and not launching it).